# Define Typescript type with properties and then any other key, but of recursive type

Tags: typescript

```
type ParameterInfo = {
    required?: true;
    pattern?: RegExp;
    // other known keys
    [otherKeys: string]: ParameterInfo;
}
```

So I can have a `ParameterInfo` with 0-many nested `ParameterInfo`s under it, e.g.:

```
{
    user: { // this is a ParameterInfo
        required: true,
        username: { // I'm a ParameterInfo, too
            required: true,
            pattern: /.../,
        },
        password: { // I'm a ParameterInfo, too
            required: true,
        },
    },
}
```

Using the type definition at the top, all of the known keys (e.g. `required`, `pattern`) are highlighted with the error:

> Property 'required' of type 'true' is not assignable to string index type 'ParameterInfo'. ts(2411)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no simple way to do this in TypeScript; see the other answer for possibilities.  By far the best way for you to deal with this is to push the recursive part down one level like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMblW), requiring refactoring of your runtime code.  Otherwise it's all going to be workarounds like the intersection.

Comment: I originally had the child params under a `parameters`  property as you suggest. It just got so verbose traversing the tree. :(