# How to select properties of object which are not keys of some type?

Tags: typescript

Suppose a type...

```
type Thing = {
    name: string;
    // other properties
};
```

...and an object which looks like this...

```
const obj = {
    name: 'blah',
    // other properties from Thing
    someProp: true,
    otherProp: 123,
    yetAnotherProp: 'yay',
};
```

...I want to be able to narrow the properties in `obj` to only those *not in* `Thing`, so the result would be:

```
const objWithoutThing = {
    // no properties from `Thing`
    someProp: true,
    otherProp: 123,
    yetAnotherProp: 'yay',
};
```

E.g.:

```
const objWithoutThing = Object
    .keys(obj)
    .filter(key => key not in keyof Thing) // obv not legit, what to put here?
    .reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: obj[key] }), {});

// now `objWithoutThing` contains all properties of `obj` except those defined on `Thing`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this automatically. TypeScript's static type system, including the definition of the `Thing` type alias, gets [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is transpiled to JavaScript.  So there will be nothing left at runtime to act upon when you try to omit the keys of `Thing` from `obj`.

---

If you want to omit the keys of `Thing` at runtime, you will need to explicitly create a list of such keys as a value that exists at runtime.  With some effort you can get the compiler to at least *check* that you've done so correctly. For example:

```
const thingKeys = ["name"] as const;

type ThingKeysCheck<
    T extends typeof thingKeys[number] = keyof Thing,
    // --------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
    // error here if thingKeys has missing keys
    U extends keyof Thing = typeof thingKeys[number]
    // -------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // error here if thingKeys has extra keys
    > = void;
```

That [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) lets the compiler realize that `thingKeys` contains the string literal `"name"` (otherwise it would just see `thingKeys` as a `string[]`).

And `ThingKeysCheck` is just there as a check to see if the string literal elements of `thingKeys` are exactly `keyof Thing`.  If there are no errors in that line, then `thingKeys` and `Thing` are consistent with each other.  Otherwise there will be an error mentioning whether keys are missing or extra or both.

---

Once you have `thingKeys`, you can use it in your filter.  The following `withoutThing()` function has a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) call signature saying that if you pass in `obj` of a type `T` assignable to `Thing` is passed in, then you will get a value of type `Omit<T, keyof Thing>` using [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

```
function withoutThing<T extends Thing>(obj: T): Omit<T, keyof Thing> {
    return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .filter(k => !(thingKeys as readonly string[]).includes(k))
        .reduce<any>((o, k) => ({ ...o, [k]: obj[k as keyof Thing] }), {});
}
```

I did a lot of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation of that function to quiet the compiler complaints; it's not very good at verifying whether you are actually creating a valid object of type `Omit<T, keyof Thing>`.  Anyway, it's basically the same implementation as you have written.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const objWithoutThing = withoutThing(obj);
console.log(objWithoutThing.someProp); // true
console.log(objWithoutThing.otherProp.toFixed(2)); // 123.00
console.log(objWithoutThing.yetAnotherProp.toUpperCase()); // "YAY"
console.log(objWithoutThing.name); // undefined
// -----------------------> ~~~~
// Property 'name' does not exist
```

Looks good to me.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8CwAoKQqJAQwFsIAuKAZ2ACdkUBufIqAeg6gHtg4I9KGHo9I9YAgg18AX1Z58AYx5I6UfkwDSEEDQxQA2gCJSFYwF0oJfSrXAF+UJFiJUOvQGEBSgNYAeNiIYKAgAD2AIJAATfWcIHgAzDTcUDxpDJABXMgAjQStMX10k1yYAGiDCLigAWnqGxqbmlsaAPigAP26e3s6qzm5BUSEBemgEZM13XX04GygyBBoaJihivQGAVVCIqNj1kuT4Ncx40um02cyc-PoLAZrW5-qOvveP98eh+hGoMYmU1S6X+C3CDBIh02BCIHUwADceAhoo48HZ1DxcgArAy4GGEMxUKAAclyABsSHBiZV8YNePxBMJROJJNIoIlRGQyqgBjQeBQAArM6gMLIQGnsPhjIViagARgATABmCVEEAQYAAQSQUsEMrA1GJIBIIGpclRiSySCUklUUAA7gh+DwssATqh-CFwft9O6UG0ABSYrHUGAASmoAHklsBPeUoaU-R08exxsAsvQkFBI9iIDaBuwAHQbGhB7FhgtEQuJBBkyL0AO+DAdACEAcuIIW4xI0VUZJAtAYTEMFjDheQSjJWWi0kbYYrtKL42iWSUEH8JCQIEDQfjvjDzagAawUELZ548cMvgs1GDV+s+g2idSVlkYfjWDfClk+GUqgx2IAOpOnALpuqkBiOs6rp+mWWJhgo6I8GSECFmSPAoHBwHQeBTCFnygrMghdKihAf5qMhqHoZhwbYaBMGpIWur0PqhbADwABiCBhBA0QBgq87MHSipKoWAAMYnkXyKFoRhWEgWBfqFuqWo6gyLHMmxPBbGA4ieDYEABoJdLGAAmpqpnGFJlGyTRQEKQxeGEsRNRWjONZILx+BPC8vm1G8PTedw+qCKAJKEsSUC9myam7MswBAA)

Comment: Yep, that makes sense and works. I was hoping TS had some magical `copykeys<T>`, or something to extract the keys to a `string[]` at runtime. I'll go with this, though. Thanks.

Comment: If you're up for another ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767666/define-typescript-type-with-properties-and-then-any-other-key-but-of-recursive

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript v3.5 or above, you can use `Omit`

```
type Obj = {
    name: string;
    someProp: boolean;
    otherProp: number;
    yetAnotherProp: string;
}

type Thing = {
    name: string;
}

type ObjWithoutThing = Omit<Obj, keyof Thing>;

const objWithoutThing: ObjWithoutThing = {
    // no properties from `Thing`
    someProp: true,
    otherProp: 123,
    yetAnotherProp: 'yay',
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but the additional properties could be literally anything, so I can't define `ObjWithoutThing` at all, its definition is "any key, except those in `Thing`".